# Select value between two characters in string SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, substring, charindex

I have a large string value that i'm looking to put into a database. I have the current code to do that.

```
DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(max) = {status}
DECLARE @DYVALUE TABLE (VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @DYVALUE (value)
SELECT @VALUE
;WITH cte
AS (
SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Value
FROM (
    SELECT CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(Value, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS Value
    FROM @DyValue
    ) AS A
CROSS APPLY Value.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
)

 insert into mytable
 SELECT *
 FROM (
SELECT replace(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Value, 0, CHARINDEX('|', value))),' ','') AS col1
    ,SUBSTRING(Value, CHARINDEX('|', Value) + 1, LEN(Value)) AS [col2]
    ,SUBSTRING(Value, CHARINDEX('/', Value) + 1, LEN(Value)) AS [col3]

FROM Cte
) dt
```

This allows me to place everything before | into column1, and everything after / into column 3.
I need to try and place everything in between the value '|' and '/' into column2

I'm struggling to get

```
   ,SUBSTRING(Value, CHARINDEX('|', Value) + 1, LEN(Value)) AS [col2]
```

to only take those values in between the two characters.

An example of the type of string this will be running on is

> 1234567890|Goodbye Cruel World/I should be in Column 3,    2345678901|Goodbye Cruel World/I should be in Column 3, 3456789012|Goodbye Cruel World/Please put me in Column 3,   3456789012|Goodbye Cruel World/Please put me in Column 3, 6324589657|Hello World/I need to be in Col 3, 1145698763|Goodbye Cruel World/I should be in Column 3, 36985214728|Goodbye Cruel World/I should be in Column 3,    7412589635|Goodbye Cruel World/I should be in Column 3, 7412589635|Goodbye Cruel World/I should be in Column 3, 6398756951|Please Help Me/Please put me in Column 3,

The string will be in that format, I've just changed the values to something slightly more amusing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using 
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3)

Answer (score 0):

If it is always three words between each comma and words are not more than 128 characters then use `PARSENAME`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Value
         FROM   (SELECT Cast('<S>' + Replace(Value, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS Value
                 FROM   @DyValue) AS A
                CROSS APPLY Value.nodes('/S') AS Split(a))
SELECT Parsename(string, 3),
       Parsename(string, 2),
       Parsename(string, 1)
FROM   (SELECT Replace(Replace(value, '|', '.'), '/', '.') string
        FROM   cte)a
```

Another way, will work with any number of characters

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Value
         FROM   (SELECT Cast('<S>' + Replace(Value, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS Value
                 FROM   @DyValue) AS A
                CROSS APPLY Value.nodes('/S') AS Split(a))
SELECT LEFT(value, Charindex('|', value) - 1),
       Substring(value, Charindex('|', value) + 1, Charindex('/', value) - Charindex('|', value) - 1),
       Substring(value, Charindex('/', value) + 1, Len(value))
FROM   cte
```

Comment: I wish it would always be three words, the amount of words will vary sorry.

Comment: @Phil - That was a example.. check now

Comment: Similar to the answer above, I get the error 
 "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function"
when trying to run this

Comment: @Phil - At the end of string there is a unwanted comma.. remove it and check

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, this might be a solution:

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(Value, 0, CHARINDEX('|', Value)) AS column1,
SUBSTRING(Value, CHARINDEX('|', Value) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', Value) 
    - CHARINDEX('|', Value) - 1) AS column2,
SUBSTRING(Value, CHARINDEX('/', Value) + 1, LEN(Value)) AS column3
```

Edit due to feedback:

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(Value, 0, CHARINDEX('|', Value)) AS column1,
SUBSTRING(Value, CHARINDEX('|', Value) + 1, 
    CHARINDEX('/', Value) - CHARINDEX('|', Value) - 1) AS column2,
SUBSTRING(Value, CHARINDEX('/', Value) + 1, LEN(Value) - CHARINDEX('/', Value)) AS column3
```

Comment: Even if I don't try to insert these into a database, I get the error

      "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function"

Comment: @Phil: Hmmm that's weird. For me it's working. I edited my answer to change the `LEN` part. Maybe that helps...